# jQuery $(this) problem

Tags: jquery, this

I write some jQuery codes as below:

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        do_sth();
    });
});

var do_sth = function(){
    console.log($(this));
}
```

I want the console.log results to be the same, but it works wrong... The first refers to a HTMLElement, but the second refers to DOMWindow...
How could I rewrite do_sth function to make them all refer to the HTMLElement?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the solution you went with.

Comment: The problem here is that the this keyword does not do what you're intending it to do. It completely depends on context. http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do...

```
do_sth.call(this);
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery's [`proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method.

```
$.proxy(do_sth, this)();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/aQrQA/).

Answer (score 4):

**1.** You can make it a prototypal function:

```
$.fn.do_sth = function() { console.log( this ); };
```

In the other fn, just do `$(this).click(function() {  $(this).do_sth(); });`

**2.** You can use `.call`

```
do_sth.call(this);
```

**3.** You can alter it to expect an element parameter:

```
function do_sth( el ) { console.log( el ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
        do_sth.call(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

pass a parameter to the function you call.

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        do_sth(this);
    });
});

var do_sth = function(button){
    console.log(button);
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JfwNJ/

Comment: few seconds slow. go figure =)

Answer (score 0):

Then, write the do_sth function to take $(this) element as a parameter:

```
var do_sth = function($el) {
  console.log($el)
}
```

Then do this:

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log($that);
        do_sth($that);
    });
});
```